# How to change a for loop to a foreach, while iterating through DataGridView control values?

Tags: c#, for-loop, datagridview, foreach

I used the following code:

```
int count = DB.Rows.Count;
for (int row = 0; row < count; row++)
{
    int colCount = DB.Rows[row].Cells.Count;

    for (int col = 0; col < colCount; col++)
    {
        filewrite.Write(DB.Rows[row].Cells[col].Value + " ");
    }

    filewrite.WriteLine("");
}
```

What I want is to rewrite this as a foreach loop, but and I'm getting this exception:

> 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection' does not contain a
>   definition for 'Cells' and no  extension method 'Cells' accepting a
>   first argument of type
>   'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection' could be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

My code:

```
foreach (DataGridView row in this.DB.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataGridView col in this.DB.Columns)
    {
        filewrite.Write(DB.Rows.Cells + " ");
    }

    filewrite.WriteLine("");
}
```

Can anyone help me or give me a hint?

EDIT

Almost got it!, now I need this loop to not read last row which is generated automatically as a empty row:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow item in this.DB.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewCell item2 in item.Cells)
    {   
        if(item2.Value != null)
        filewrite.Write(item2.Value.ToString() + " ");
    }

    filewrite.WriteLine("");
}
```

How to omit the last empty row?

Comment: Shouldn't your first foreach be of type `DataGridViewRow` and the second `DataGridViewColumn`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code out:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.DB.Rows)
{
    // Add this to break the loop when row is last blank row
    if (row.IsNewRow)
        break;

    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
    {
        if (cell.Value != null)
            filewrite.Write(cell.Value.ToString() + " ");
    }
    file.WriteLine();
}
```

I assume you're trying to print out all the values from cells in each row to your text file. If that's the case, this should complete the task.